# Автоматический подбор цвета по изображению

Tags: java, javafx

Каким образом в JavaFX можно реализовать автоматический подбор цветов по изображению?
Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посчтитать количество пикселей по цветам, именно по HUE из цветности HSB. Это бутет наша гистограмма. А потом выбрать "окно" какой-то ширины и пройтись по нашей гистограмме ищя максимум, суммируя количество пикселей в этом окно. Найденый максимум и будеи основным тоном. Код писать не буду, с телефона сижу

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko не совсем понял момент с HUE. Можно ли код,пожалуйста?

Comment: Hsb или Hsv. Система цветности, где H отвечает за цвет, осталтные два параметра это насыщенность и яркость. Стандартный рисунок хранится в RGB то есть в представлении трех цветлв. Нужно преобразовать цвет каждого писеля в HSB и получить первый параметр цвета. И потом посчитать каких цветов больше. Ну а дальше покрасить нужные элементы в этот цвет. К сожалению кода не будет. Нет доступа к компьютеру

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать библиотеку `OpenCV` и метод `K-Means Clustering`[для python](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html).
Вообще на питоне я делал так:

## Функция опредеоения лидирующих цветов

```
    def __detect_primary_colors(self, single_template):
        '''
        :param single_template: Путь к изображнию шаблона для анализа
        :return: Массив трех лидируюших цветов
        '''
        single_photo = cv2.imread(single_template)
        hue_color_name = [
            [355, 360, "Red"],
            [346, 355, "Pink-Red"],
            [331, 345, "Pink"],
            [321, 330, "Magenta-Pink"],
            [281, 320, "Magenta"],
            [241, 280, "Blue-Magenta"],
            [221, 240, "Blue"],
            [201, 220, "Cyan-Blue"],
            [170, 200, "Cyan"],
            [141, 169, "Green-Cyan"],
            [81, 140, "Green"],
            [61, 80, "Yellow-Green"],
            [51, 60, "Yellow"],
            [41, 50, "Orange-Yellow"],
            [21, 40, "Orange-Brown"],
            [11, 20, "Red-Orange"],
            [1, 10, "Red"]
        ]

        '''
            Конвертация в HSV для работы
            Нарезка HSV на составляющие hue, saturation, value
            Постороение гистограммы по модели HSV
        '''
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(single_photo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        hue, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
        hue_hist, bins = np.histogram(hue, 360)
        hues = {}

        i = 0
        while i < len(hue_color_name):
            if hue_color_name[i][2] in hues:
                hues[hue_color_name[i][2]] = hues.get(hue_color_name[i][2]) + np.sum(
                    hue_hist[hue_color_name[i][0]:hue_color_name[i][1]])
            else:
                hues[hue_color_name[i][2]] = (np.sum(hue_hist[hue_color_name[i][0]:hue_color_name[i][1]]))
            i += 1

        s_hues = sorted(hues, key=hues.get, reverse=True)
return [s_hues[0], s_hues[1], s_hues[2]]
```

Ну а вообще `OpenCV Java` существует и разбирайся с ней.

Comment: вы язык видите?

Comment: @michael_best `OpenCV` есть в `JavaFX`... Посмотрите документацию

Comment: для чего приводить пример на питоне?

Comment: @michael_best там практически не отличается работа. Пример на `python` - есть реализая твоей задачи. Тебе надо лишь ее адаптировать под `JavaFX`

Comment: это не моя задача)